# android webservice to a php server (XML vs JSON and SOAP vs REST)

Tags: php, android, xml, json, soap

I am actually looking for some opinion on how to get this done. I have a php server with a mysql backend to authenticate users using android os. I came across the debate of having JSON vs XML to minimize the overhead and using REST vs SOAP. Can I get some tips on what is the best path to go about getting this done ? I know its a trade-off if I use JSON/REST because its a bit complicated than XML/SOAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON/REST is simpler than XML/SOAP. It has less overhead since you don't need the extra SOAP portions of the message. Also Android has JSON parseing APIs.